# Best Approach to Create and Deploy Configurable Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vcenter

I am new to Vmware APIs, is there some way to use Rest/Soap APIs to deploy a VM on a given IP of either an ESXi Server or a Vcentre Server?

I know there exists CreateVM_Task in VSphere Web Services SDK but how to use it for an ESXi Server on a remote location?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and the code you are running issues with it.

Comment: Hi Sami..I have tried following code provided on git for creating VM using the VCenter API..Just wondering how to do the same directly on ESXi Server without a Vcenter Server.( https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/vmware/samples/vcenter/vm/create/basicvm/CreateBasicVM.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you run the sample the exact same way. However you authenticate to the ESXi host directly instead of the vCenter server.

Now that I think about it, you'll probably also have to remove the datacenter parameter since hosts don't contain datacenter objects.

Comment: Thanks for replying Kyle! You're right running the sample exact way works.Also, I added the data center name as found in Service Content of to https://ESXi_IP/mob/.In my case it was ha-datacenter.